# Add material-UI svg icons one inside another in IconButton

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a requirement where I have to show a search icon with circle ⭕️ covered. I mean a circle with a search icon inside it and when I handover mouse a tooltip has to be shown.

I can achieve this using FlotingActionButton with svg icon but the problem is I can’t place tooltip on it.

So as I know the alternative is using IconButton with svg icon. This has an option to set tooltip. So I integrated it as like below

```
 import IconButton from ‘material-ui/IconButton’;
 import SearchIcon from ‘material-ui/svg-icons/action/search’;
 import Lens from ‘material-UI/svg-icons/image/lens’;

 <IconButton tooltip=“Click to Search”>
      <Lens color=“red”>
            <SearchIcon color=“white” />
      </Lens>
 </IconButton>
```

But the issue here is I can only see circle but search icon not appearing inside Lens. Any suggestions what am I doing wrong? Or is there any other way that I can achieve with tooltip? Please suggest

Comment: What version of material-ui do you use? If `0.xx` check my answer.

Comment: I am using v0.18

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to place one icon into another but you can show tooltip over `FlotingActionButton`. There is an internal material-ui component `Tooltip`. It is not documented but you can import it this way:

```
import Tooltip from "material-ui/internal/Tooltip";
```

Create this simple component:

```
class TooltipHolder extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isVisible: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ position: 'relative' }}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ isVisible: true })}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ isVisible: false })}
      >
        {this.props.children}

        <Tooltip
          label={this.props.label}
          show={this.state.isVisible}
          horizontalPosition="center"
          verticalPosition="top"
          touch={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can use this component in your `render` method and every time when user will hover over the component that you pass as a child for `TooltipHolder` the tooltip will show.

```
<TooltipHolder label="tooltip text">
  <FloatingActionButton mini={true}>
    <SearchIcon />
  </FloatingActionButton>
</TooltipHolder>
```

Check [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/20rq468720) for the situation that you described.

Comment: Thank you Mikhali. Great. I was under impression that material-UI 0.xx version doesn’t have Tooltip component separately. I will test your code and update you.